# ParseUser.CurrentUser is not cached between sessions

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, parse-platform, mbaas

I am developing a MonoGame app for Windows Phone 8. I am using the .Net SDK of Parse for my backend services. I login the user using

```
ParseUser user = await ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(browser, null);
```

This redirects the app to the web browser for login and automatically returns back into the app after login is finished or cancelled. At this point I can call **ParseUser.CurrentUser** to get the current logged in Facebook user (null if not logged in). According to Parse's [docs](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#fbusers):

> It would be bothersome if the user had to log in every time they open
>   your app. You can avoid this by using the cached ParseUser.CurrentUser
>   object.
>
> Whenever you use any signup or login methods, the user is cached on
>   disk. You can treat this cache as a session, and automatically assume
>   the user is logged in

So after I login, I restart the app expecting **ParseUser.CurrentUser** to return the previously logged in user, but it doesn't, instead returning null, so I have to login again.
I cant tell if am doing something wrong or if it is a bug.

Comment: I have the same issue on Android with Parse 1.5.1

Comment: @Ramsay Hi, did you find out the solution? I faced the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you using/enabling the local datastore in Parse?

If yes, your issue might relate to this: https://www.parse.com/questions/android-local-datastore-getcurrentuser

Comment: No I was not aware of enabling the local datastore bit. Either way I have long abandoned Parse for Facebook and implemented my own login flow, so currently I cant confirm if the info in your link actually fixes the issue... I might recheck in the future.